# Рисование наклонных линий в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

То, что я пытаюсь сделать, ВЫГЛЯДИТ просто, но я не могу понять, как это сделать.
Как вы можете видеть на моем изображении, есть пара красных линий, которые проходят через нижнюю часть, затем изгибаются вверх к правой стороне.

Есть ли способ в CSS нарисовать такую линию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Drawing angled lines in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29982414/7394871) от участника  [@Sherwin Flight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979573/sherwin-flight).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/29982414/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете создавать наклонные линии в CSS, используя преобразования наклона (transform: skew(Xdeg)). Ниже приведен образец кода:

```css
.shape {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Двойная линия, одна из которых находится над областью содержимого, а другая - за ней, также может быть выполнена с использованием одного элемента (и пары псевдо), как в приведенном ниже фрагменте:

```css
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #D0D0D0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  Some text that goes within the element...
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29982491/7394871) от участника  [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry).</sub>